# Can't blender do a snap like the Sketchup?

Tags: snapping

[image]

Sketch-ups snap to the left corner and move.

[image]

Blender doesn't sort by left.
I know it's based on active after changing the origin.
It's very uncomfortable. Is there any simple way to cut short?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42710/translate-like-sketchup-move

Comment: What if you just work right to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

it is possible in edit mode.
select vertext and press A and move it

Comment: You don't need to be in Edit Mode for this if you use "Snap with Closest"

Comment: closest is not accurate. see 2 image. wrong snap

Answer (score 2):

In Object mode you have to move object to the right, release, than grab again and Snap.

[image]

Comment: it's good. but i want to move direct. no move to right.

Comment: I know :) I just wanted to show how blender snap works. In blender matter from what side are  you comming. Your answer is pointing  drag and snap. I upvoted your answer. I didnt know I can snap like that. Better that nothing :)

Comment: ah. also i don't know your way. thank you for your answer. but it's not that i want. sorry

Comment: I didn't expect you will mark answer as accepted (solution) :) I understood your first comment.